# How to select first 'li' automatically after opening drop-down?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu like this. It can be view [ON MY WEBSITE](http://www.carantina.com) under **PRODUCTS** tab

QUESTION 1:
Under product page you will see the picture below.

[image]

What I want is when I hover on products page I want the first items to be active automatically.

This is what it will show when I click products page.

[image]

QUESTION 2:
In addition to this, if I hover on first item and move my cursor the right pane, the first item's background shall be still hover style ( which is blue ).

Presently, if I move my mouse to the right content pane, the background becomes white.

QUESTION 3:
If I click any items in the left list, the content in the right pane doesn't change automatically as I hover on other items in the list. If I don't click any items it works perfectly. The problem is when I click to any items.

I had written a jquery code for that but I think I am missing something.

```
$('.urun_tab').hover( function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('hoverblock'))
        return;
    else
        $(this).find('a').tab('show');
});


$('.urun_tab').find('a').click( function(){
    $(this).parent()
            .siblings().addClass('hoverblock');
});
```

This is the items part on my website

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs span4">
    <li class="active urun_tab"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">Seksiyonel Kapılar<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a> </li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">Otomatik Kapılar<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">Kepenk ve Panjur Sistemleri<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#D" data-toggle="tab">Hangar Kapıları<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#E" data-toggle="tab">Otomasyon Ürünleri<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#F" data-toggle="tab">Yükleme Sistemleri<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#G" data-toggle="tab">Yangın Kapıları<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you have three questions, post three separate SO questions with clear test cases for each. Omnibus questions aren't a very good practice when it comes to attracting good answers quickly. (Yes, this is more work on your part. This is why it's less work on the part of the people answering, hence the quicker answers.)

Comment: I am just trying to fill SO with unnecessary new posts. Most of them could be solved by same people. That is the reason which we can see a demonstration of it in this question.

Comment: You're going to get a lot of answers spanning a lot of different topics from a lot of different people. Makes it very difficult to answer the whole lot in one go. As @millimoose recommended, you should make 3 different posts for 3 different questions.

Comment: @SNaRe SO is a QA site, not a forum. This gets repeated endlessly but has more consequences than are immediately apparent. One is that "spamming with topics" is not a bad thing, because of the tagging and the ability to view unanswered questions etc. Another thing is that SO aims to build an "expert knowledge base" or so - that is, a question and its associated answer should (ideally) have some value for a person searching on Google for a similar issue. Questions that tackle a class of problem are better than "pls debug my live site me".

Answer (score 1):

in css on line number 127 please paste these changes

```
    .navbar .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li:active, .navbar .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li:hover, .navbar .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li:focus, .navbar .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li:hover > a, .navbar .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li:active > a,.nav-tabs > li.active 
    {
       background-color: #477390;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
.nav-tabs > li.active  > a {color:#fff !important;}
```

Comment: I pasted. However, nothing has changed.

Comment: Updated. But nothing changed.

Comment: How exactly does CSS achieve selecting an item in a Javascript widget? Also, the OP should provide an actual test case for his problem, not just screenshots, and you should test your answers against said test case, instead of doing this wild guess back and forth.

Comment: because active class is already implemented on list and all he need is call css according to the class and i added that css

Comment: @Hushme I changed line 127 as you said. Just check yourself.

Comment: @millimoose I couldn't put actual test case for this problem because this is a megadropdown and it toggles automatically when you hover on item. Thus, in order to see result, you have to do some action.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. Just a small question, the color of the text is black rather than white. It becomes white right after I hover on the same item.

Comment: I added but it doesn't work. Can you check again. I won't leave without accepting your answer. Don't works. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Yes it works. Last question and I will thank to you and accept answer. When I hover on PRODUCTS page 1 time and leave that toggle, the blue bar on the top of 'PRODUCTS' remains there. If I leave the toggle, it shall disappear too. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: add your active class js code in question where you are adding active class on hover

Comment: @SNaRe By test case I didn't mean some automated code that outputs a "pass" / "fail", I meant a simplified webpage (or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [pen](http://codepen.io/)) that shows your problem in practice, *and nothing else*. That is, with as much styling etc as possible stripped away so there's less code to wade through.

Comment: @SNaRe Also, "one more question and I will accept" is a bad practice, you're demanding ever more attention from whoever bothered to click on your question in the first place. It's better to aim for short question lifecycles - that way you'd more likely have three people answering your three subquestions, which would be much quicker than you having to poke *Hushme* for an hour.